# can't click install button while using "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" permission

Tags: android-manifest, android-install-apk

can't click install button while use my app.

I use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

Below my code:

```
new WindowManager.LayoutParams( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                 PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

If use my app, Can't click install button while install apk file.

how can i use install button?

Answer (score 1):

Only delete windows and start after installing..

Comment: but Swipepad(App) is possible. how can that possible??

Answer (score 1):

first, try this code.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,              
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,   
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,     
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

and if you want give position, use this.
default position is center.

```
params.gravity = Gravity.~~~~;
```

if you want bottom-right position, do as below code

```
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
```

it'll works fine maybe.
but still can't click on your view when click install button:can click outside your view when click install button.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you window "fill" all screen. Try this to show an 1px x 1px window :

```
new WindowManager.LayoutParams( 1, 1,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
             PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! Thanks.

Comment: Over and over again tested. I found out that the width + height must not exceed 97% of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security measure in Android.  There is no work-around.  https://blog.lookout.com/blog/2010/12/09/android-touch-event-hijacking/